# RestyGWT & GWT integration

Tags: java, resty-gwt

repost:

**OBJECTIVE:**

I'm using GWT and trying to call an existing Twitter REST Service using RestyGWT client

**PROBLEM**:

I am not receiving a response to my GET request to "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json" , or another json.

THINGS I'VE TRIED:

I've looked at RestyGWT's documentation, and I couldn't come across a concrete example on how to call third party REST services. Tried calling a REST service using plaintext return types, same problem. There must be something I'm doing wrong on a fundamental leve.

**CODE:**

Here's my onModuleLoad:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

Resource r = new Resource("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json");

        r.get().send(new JsonCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Method method, JSONValue response) {
                System.out.println("Twitter response:\tYES");
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
                System.out.println("Twitter response:\tNO");
                System.out.println("Exception:\t\t"+exception.toString());
                System.out.println("Exception Message:\t"+exception.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Status code:\t\t"+method.getResponse().getStatusCode() );
                }
        });}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
GWT MODULE LOADED
Twitter response:   NO
Exception:          org.fusesource.restygwt.client.FailedStatusCodeException: 
Exception Message:  
Status code:        0
```

Comment: You are trying to do a Cross site requests, first have a look to http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/cross-site-requests-with-gwt-restygwt-and-html5-cors/

and maybe https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/restygwt/csrf/restygwt/C6F6VXx_A6A/VvQfbmFlBH4J

Then you need to be authenticated for this call. You should received a 215 error if not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by "_" symbol in your request. Try to use another URL, or add CharacterEncodingFilter on server side in web.xml. something like this:

```
        <filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```